# Using Dictionary get method to return empty list by default returns None instead

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In Python I would like to build up an dictionary of arrays using the dictionary get method to by default supply an empty list to then populate with information e.g.:

```
dct = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        dct[i] = dct.get(i, []).append(j)
```

However when I try the above code I get no exceptions but my list ends up like the following:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Lists have an `append` method, so I simplified my test to the following:

```
dct = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
    dct[i] = dct.get(i, []).append(i)
```

And the output was the following:

> {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}

So my question is why is `dct.get(i, [])` returning `None` by default and not `[]`?  Doing `dct.get(i, list())` has the same problem, so I am a bit stumped.

Comment: Please please please do not use `dict` as a variable name. It clashes with the built-in `dict` class.

Comment: I don't typically do that, I just wanted to be clear as to what the variable was.

Comment: You don't want the `dict[i] =` in front of the `setdefault`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Your first setdefault code is flawed, don't assign back to dict[i].       `dict.setdefault( i, [] ).append( j )` should be all you need.

Comment: Your correct, I just figured that out.  May thanks, I wish I could make you all as correct :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not `dict.get( i, [] )` that's returning `None`, it's `append`. You probably want to use `dict.setdefault(i, []).append(j)` or just use a `defaultdict` in the first place.

Here's how you would do it:

```
d = {}
for i in range( 0, 10 ):
    for j in range( 0, 100 ):
        d.setdefault( i, [] ).append( j )
```

Note that I changed `dict` to `d` because `dict` already means something in Python (you're redefining it) and I removed the superfluous `dict[i] =` that was causing the error message.

Answer (score 39):

To solve this you should use Python's `defaultdict`. The first time you use a key that doesn't exist, the argument to the defaultdict constructor is used to create a value (in this case, a list).

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

```
from collections import defaultdict 

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range( 0, 10 ):
    for j in range( 0, 100 ):
        d[i].append( j )
```

You can also pass a function as the argument to defaultdict if you want to do anything more elaborate.

Comment: This is the right answer. There are no bonus points in Python for 'rolling your own'.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `append` returns `None` instead of the list object. So

`dict[i] = dict.get( i, [] ).append( j )` assigns None to `dict[i]`

However, you can do much simpler:

```
dict.setdefault( i, [] ).append( j )
```

.. quoting the docs for `setdefault`:

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default

So if the key `i` is not yet present it creates it and stores the default value in it, in either case it returns the key value - which is a reference to the list, so you can modify it directly.

Comment: Doing the append and setdefault on the same line caused an exception for me on Python 2.7.1.

Comment: Works for me with both 2.6 and 3.1

Comment: by far the best answer

Answer (score 4):

`append` doesn't return a list.  It appends the value to the list and returns `None`.

Instead of this:

```
 dict[i] = dict.get( i, [] ).append( j )
```

You could do this:

```
 dict.setdefault(i, [])
 dict[i].append( j )
```

Comment: or, on one line: `dict.setdefault(i, []).append( j )` - although it should be noted that defaultdict is faster.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that uses the `get` method by taking advantage of list addition.

```
d = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        d[i] = d.get(i, []) + [j]
```

Comment: Problem is this requires first making a one element list out of `j` in order to take advantage of it.