# Empty dict as default value of dict.get()

Tags: python, dictionary, default

I am attempting to pass an empty dictionary as the default return value of a call to `.get()`on another dictionary.

```
queryStringParameters = event.get('queryStringParameters', ({})
size = queryStringParameters.get('size', 25)
```

However, `queryStringParameters.get(...)` throws an error saying that queryStringParameters is `None`.

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/api/game.py", line 13, in all
size = queryStringParameters.get('size', 25)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Is this not possible, or am I doing something wrong? I have tried the following as well:

```
queryStringParameters = event.get('queryStringParameters', dict())
```

Comment: It is perfectly possible for `event.get('queryStringParameters', {})` to return `None`. Observe an equivalent example: `event = {'a':None}; event.get('a', {})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Dictionary get method to return empty list by default returns None instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772148/using-dictionary-get-method-to-return-empty-list-by-default-returns-none-instead)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chances are that `event` actually contains a key `queryStringParameters` that happens to be `None`. Did you check if the key exists?

The default value is only returned if the key does not exists, not if it exists and happens to be None.

But you can also write

```
queryStringParameters = event.get('queryStringParameters', {}) or {}
```

to be on the safe side.

Comment: I think the problem here is the OP was being *too "safe"*.

Comment: I'd rather explicitly check if it is None. Because if the value already is an empty dict, you wont get that instance but a newly created one. Might be no issue, but depends on how other parts of OPs program use `event` and the dictionaries within it...